# Error: oneof field 'queries' is already set. Cannot set 'queryList' with terraform Gcloud dataproc

Tags: terraform-provider-gcp

Problem Explanation:..
I am trying to submit a Hive job on an existing Dataproc cluster(dcl-hive) I created on GCP through Terraform but stuck with an issue for quite a while for which I tried google resources and unable to resolve.

In dataproc cluster hive job block I have just given a simple hive script to create external table using a csv stored in gcloud storage bucket, and I am also able to submit this job through Gcloud cli but when i supply the same config in terraform resource block, it throws the below error. The code and error is pasted below.

code snippet:

main.tf

```
resource "google_dataproc_job" "hive-job" {
    region       = var.region
    force_delete = true
    placement {
    cluster_name = "dcl-hive"
}
   hive_config {
   query_file_uri = "gs://hive-warehouse-simran/datasets/account-status-ext-table-script.q"
}
}
```

Hive query script:(account-status-ext-table-script.q)

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS lref_account_status_ext
(
ACCOUNT_STATUS_CODE CHAR(10),
ACCOUNT_STATUS_DESC CHAR(30),
RECORD_STATUS CHAR(10),
CREATED_BY STRING,
CREATED_TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP,
MODIFIED_BY VARCHAR(50),
MODIFIED_TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP,
COMMENTS CHAR(255)
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
location 'gs://hive-warehouse/datasets'
tblproperties ("skip.header.line.count"="1");
select \* from lref_account_status_ext;
```

Problem Explanation continued:..
The last block is where I am getting stuck with this error ---
[image]
In the documentation it is written everywhere to either provide query list or query file uri has an HCFS path to file where hive query is written so I am doing the same. In the error it says - Cannot set query list where I am just providing Query file uri and not query list literally.

GCLI command that worked to submit hive job and get the output in dataproc cluster:

gcloud dataproc jobs submit hive 
--cluster dcl-hive 
--region ${REGION} 
--file="gs://hive-warehouse/datasets/account-status-ext-table-script.q";